# Linking to Other Website Page With Icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I am using Icons From Font Awesome and am using the Font Awesome gem in my rails app. How can I make the icon link to my profile on another application? Can I use an ERB tag with a link_to that specific url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to(fa_icon('stack-overflow'), 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/') %>
```